# Authentication/Authorization with ASP .NET Core and React based on Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

I've been trying to create a SPA web application using React with ASP .NET Core 3.1 as backend, and now I need to restrict users going to certain pages. I know that for API methods I can do the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Whatever> Get(){ ... }
```

But that would only block users from using the API methods, which is good, but I also want to not let them go into the pages themselves.

Since I do not want to use their Blazor pages (because it breaks the separation of the client app and the backend), I cannot scaffold their login page, so I created mine using React and then implemented login and logout methods, which work, since when I'm logged in, the **AspNetCore.Identity.Application** cookie appears.

In order to do this, I added the following lines to **Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication (o => 
     {
         o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
         o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
     }).AddIdentityCookies(o => {});
    
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    ...
}
```

Now I've read (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055744/14806778) that, in React, you can define an **onEnter** method and check authentication there. So, to check if user is logged in or not, I implemented the simple method:

```
public bool IsUserLoggedIn()
{
    return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

This also works, so I guess I could call this method in the **onEnter** method of React routing. I don't know if that's efficient or not, though.

Last, to check if user is in role, I could do something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> IsUserInRole(string requiredRole)
{
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        return await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, requiredRole);
    } 
    return false;
}
```

And call this **onEnter** instead.

My question is, is this approach valid? Is it safe? Does it have a huge performance impact? What are the alternatives? I've looked around a bit but I haven't seen a lot. I've read about JWT but I don't know how is it so different to this.

Also, I don't need Google/Apple/Facebook login, this is for an app which will be most likely running on localhost inside a VPN. I am using .NET Core 3.1, React 16.14 and React router dom 5.2.0.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am trying to do this myself. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using OAuth2, it's not very difficult to implement and saves a lot of hassle.

Comment: @anon37894203  - do you mean just going with server rendered pages?