# How to stay login after refresh the page in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when i refresh the page , the page automatically return false isLogin. i dont know, i already tried many times and ask to stackoverflow but no result. as we know . the browser will refresh the page if we try to edit the code and save it. and then wehen i try to console the props isloggin, when i login it return true, but whenn refresh the page, it return false. @.@

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

import "assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css";
import "assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "assets/scss/argon-dashboard-react.scss";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";
import reducer from './components/reducers'
import LandingLogin from './layouts/LandingLogin.js'
import LandingRegister from './layouts/LandingRegister.js'


const store = createStore(reducer);
const customHistory = createHashHistory();



ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
      <Router history={customHistory}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/" render= {() => <LandingLogin/>} />
          <Route exact path="/login" render= {() => <LandingLogin/>} />
          <Route exact path="/register" render= {() => <LandingRegister/>} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

login.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { userLogin } from '../../actions/index'
import axios from 'axios';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

// reactstrap components
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  FormGroup,
  Form,
  Input,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  InputGroup,
  Col
} from "reactstrap";

const customHistory = createHashHistory();

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        post : [],
        formData : {
          id : '',
          first_name : '',
          last_name : '',
          email : '',
          gender : '',
          password: '',
        },
        isLogedIn : true

      }
      this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
      this.submitLogin = this.submitLogin.bind(this);
    }

    getPostAPI = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8001/datauser')
      .then((res) => {
          this.setState ({
              post : res.data
          })
      })
    }

    getPostAPI2 = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8001/dataadmin')
      .then((res) => {
          this.setState ({
              post : res.data
          })
      })
    }

    handleForm = (e) => {
      let formDataNew = {...this.state.formData};
      formDataNew[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
        formData : formDataNew
      })

    }

    loadValues = () => {
      this.setState({
        formData: [`{"email": "${this.state.formData.email}","password": "${this.state.formData.password}"}`],
      }, () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('formData', this.state.formData)
      })
    }

    submitLogin = (event) => {
      const { dispatch } = this.props;
      const {post} = this.state;    
      if(post.find(e =>  `${e.email}${e.password}` === `${this.state.formData.email}${this.state.formData.password}` )) {
        dispatch(userLogin(this.state.formData.email, this.state.formData.password));
        this.loadValues();
              customHistory.push('/admin/index');
      }else  {
        alert("Email atau Password Salah!");
        this.setState ({
          formData : {
            email : '',
            password: ''
          },


        })

      }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      this.getPostAPI2();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
              <Col lg="5" md="7">
                <Card className="bg-secondary shadow border-0">
                  <CardBody className="px-lg-5 py-lg-5">
                  <div className="text-center text-muted mb-4">
                      <h2>Form Login</h2>
                  </div>
                    <Form role="form">
                      <FormGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                          <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                            <InputGroupText>
                              <i className="ni ni-email-83" />
                            </InputGroupText>
                          </InputGroupAddon>
                          <Input onChange={this.handleForm} value={this.state.formData.email} name = "email" placeholder="Email" type="email" />
                        </InputGroup>
                      </FormGroup>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                          <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                            <InputGroupText>
                              <i className="ni ni-lock-circle-open" />
                            </InputGroupText>
                          </InputGroupAddon>
                          <Input onChange={this.handleForm} value={this.state.formData.password} name = "password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                        </InputGroup>
                      </FormGroup>
                      <div className="custom-control custom-control-alternative custom-checkbox">
                        <input
                          className="custom-control-input"
                          id=" customCheckLogin"
                          type="checkbox"
                        />
                        <label
                          className="custom-control-label"
                          htmlFor=" customCheckLogin"
                        >
                          <span className="text-muted">Remember me</span>
                        </label>
                      </div>

                      <div className="text-center">
                        <Button onClick={this.submitLogin} className="my-4" color="primary" type="button">
                        Log in
                      </Button>
                      </div>
                    </Form>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>

            </Fragment>
          );
        }
      }

      function select(state) {
        return {
          users: state.users
        }
      }

      export default connect(select)(Login);
```

reducers users.js

```
import { USER_LOGIN, USER_LOGOUT} from '../../constants/ActionTypes';


const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: false
  }


export default function users(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN:
        return Object.assign({}, state, response(state, action));
    case USER_LOGOUT:
        return Object.assign({}, state, logout());

    default:
      return state
  }

function response(state){

  state.isLoggedIn = true;
  return state

}

function logout(){
    state.isLoggedIn = false;
    return state;
    }
}
```

actiontype.js

```
export const USER_LOGIN = 'USER_LOGIN'
export const USER_LOGOUT = 'USER_LOGOUT'
```

actions.js

```
import { USER_LOGIN, USER_LOGOUT} from '../constants/ActionTypes'

export function userLogin(email, password) {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGIN,
        email: email,
        password: password,
    };
}

export function userLogout() {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGOUT
    };
}
```

im be pleasure if i to know how should i do,

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097440/on-react-router-how-to-stay-logged-in-state-even-refresh-the-page

Comment: response and logout are mutating state, don't do that, just return `{...state,isLoggedIn : true}` If you want to save isLoggedIn then use localstorage and get the value when you set initial state, set the value when you login or out but don't do it in the reducer because reducers need to be pure do it in middleware or useEffect

Comment: i will try ur suggestion, i will reporty to thsi ocmment if i succes or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On React Router, how to stay logged in state even refresh the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097440/on-react-router-how-to-stay-logged-in-state-even-refresh-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the package `redux-persist`. This contains a function `persistStore` and the `PersistGate` component. This will rehydrate the store after reloading the page. And you have to choose in wich browser store the data will be saved. You can decide between session storage (per tab) or locale storage (per domain)

Here is the example for session storage

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage/session'

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store)
const customHistory = createHashHistory();



ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
...
```

Comment: i change all the reducer, i put it into main.js a.k.a index.js